# About determinism and any relevant views

Tags: determinism, materialism, emergence

Is there a term or set of concepts regarding what one might call non-materialistic determinism? The possible idea determinism might not only apply to sets of interacting physical 'things' but also to identifiable patterns ( however complicated ) in the changing dynamics of a 'set of things'. One could call such identifiable , possibly predictable patterns 'meta- things' or 'emergent-pattern dynamic constructions'. {Emergent or non-reducible in the sense if 'further' analysed and only 'parts' of the pattern are 'focused' on the whole pattern as it is 'existing' will have some of its features 'out-of focus' or partly obscured and as such the 'whole' pattern will not be 'properly observed'.} So these 'meta things' or 'meta - objects' involving actual dynamic systems of physical objects if they are identifiable and 'independent' ( in the sense they as a whole have qualities that are not only dependent on 'parts' of their 'sub-systems'); these meta - objects could 'interact' with other 'meta - objects' and/or objects in ways that are describable by deterministic principles. Is all this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

If the patterns are made up of deterministically-acting things, then their interactions will ultimately be deterministic.  "Ah", but you say, "I know *that* but I want to forget about all the components and only work at the higher level of patterns!"

Then it's feasible...until it's not.

Colliding billiard balls make a good example.  They have, to a good approximation, elastic collisions, and so their trajectories can be described deterministically (at least if they are on a very slippery surface like teflon).  You can even come up with nice deterministic terms to correct for imperfect elasticity and so on.  This works until you smash them together too hard, at which point they start undergoing plastic deformation and cracking, and exactly when that happens and which pieces fly off in what direction is determined in part by the microstructure of the balls that was completely irrelevant at lower speeds.

For the high-level pattern to be true in *all* cases you would need the internal binding energy of the objects to be drastically greater than any externally imparted energy, and/or (for dynamical systems) you'd need attractor dynamics with such a deep well that no perturbation could push you out of it.  (You may need other things as well; details matter a lot here.)  I am not aware of a way to guarantee such a thing in a real-world situation, though of course one can always make toy models with this property.

Comment: But isn't recognizing and manipulating patterns of info. of real processes of processes involved in mathematics and how they can predictably and 'deterministically' interact a big part of physics and mathematical analysis?

Comment: Non-materialistic determinism could apply to ideas and recognizable sets of patterns of interacting ideas and how prediction models could apply to them..

Comment: @201044 - There are no dynamics there in the usual sense of the word (once you are entirely mathematical).  Also, this is what I characterized as a "toy model".  Maybe just "model" would be more charitable.  It represents something, but it you push too hard the real thing will break in not-high-level-deterministic ways, and then the model won't be a good model any more (so it's kind of beside the point how deterministic it is).

Comment: If one can successfully manipulate recognizable 'non-reducible' patterns of info. by using certain deterministic methods one is actually manipulating ideas that are non-materialistic or 'abstract' and one is using deterministic methods ; so 'non-materialistic determinism'.

Comment: @201044 - I still don't understand what you're getting at.  Are you trying to reinvent group theory?  Are you just noting that mathematics is normally described non-temporally but without randomness so that if you apply it temporally you get a deterministic process?  I strongly suspect that the use of the word "determinism" is hindering rather than helping matters.

Comment: I'm using the term non-materialistic determinism in ways that are not about Mathematics or Logic. I'm thinking more about Physics and Philosophy. Determinism in Physics and philosophy usually refers to material objects and how they 'interact' and how their interacting behaviour can be 'modelled' and predicted by various deterministic principles like the  'Laws of Physics'. So could there then be a 'kind' of determinism that handles 'non-materialistic' objects or 'abstract objects'?

Comment: @201044 - Mathematics handles abstract objects of all sorts.  Computer science does loads of interactions of such objects in deterministic ways (adding integers, for instance).  Also, "determinism" is a statement about causality with a time dimension.  I don't see any time dimension in what you're proposing.  If it is connected to the universe in any way, then my answer above stands: it will break.  Otherwise, I think you are forgetting that determinism is just saying that material objects go along obeying math, like non-material concepts do!

Comment: Any type of algorithm that is developed with deterministic 'processes' often requires precise scheduels and timing when certain sub-systems of the algorithm are to be active and what other 'parts' they interact with and for how long. So a type of determinism could apply to certain abstract algorithms and how they interact.

Comment: If physicalism is wrong and there are some real things in the universe that can not be explained ONLY as a sequence of events (of various three dimensional configurations of physical matter) that occur in some required order (for the specific thing to exist or be existing as a process) then if materialism is still useful as a way of thinking this all could be termed non-physical materialism.